# jqGrid treegrid ignores expanded state when provided xml data

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, treegrid

I have this problem, treegrid in jqGrid ignores the last option (expanded node or not) when passing data through xml. Anyone encountered this? Is there a solution? Maybe its my data? Here is a sample data that produces the problem:

```
<rows>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>0</total>
    <records>4</records>
    <row id='2'>
            <cell>2</cell>
            <cell>Parent</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
            <cell>NULL</cell>
            <cell>false</cell>
            <cell>true</cell>
          </row>
    <row id='1'>
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell>Child 1</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell>2</cell>
            <cell>true</cell>
            <cell>false</cell>
          </row>
    <row id='3'>
            <cell>3</cell>
            <cell>Child 2</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell>2</cell>
            <cell>true</cell>
            <cell>false</cell>
          </row>
    <row id='4'>
            <cell>4</cell>
            <cell>Child 3</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell>2</cell>
            <cell>true</cell>
            <cell>false</cell>
          </row>
</rows>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for me more as a bug in TreeGrid. Nevertheless you can easy fix the problem by **adding `loaded: true` property to the node which need be expanded**. The reason in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.treegrid.js#L68) of code and some above lines (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.treegrid.js#L53-59)) where `loaded` property (and `ldat[loaded]`) will be `undefined` and so the `ldat[expanded]` will be changed to `undefined` for all items having no `loaded` defined.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTreeXml1_.htm) demonstrate the solution. It uses XML which you posted but with additional `<cell>true</cell>` added at the end of definition of `"Parent"` item:

```xml
...
<row id='2'>
    <cell>2</cell>
    <cell>Parent</cell>
    <cell>0</cell>
    <cell>NULL</cell>
    <cell>false</cell>
    <cell>true</cell>
    <cell>true</cell> <!-- added the element for loaded: true -->
</row>
...
```

**UPDATED**: I think that the most easy way to fix the bug (originally described [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/treegrid/jqgrid-4-adjacency-model-expanded_field-problem/#p23012)) will be to change [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.treegrid.js#L68) of code `setTreeNode`

```
ldat[expanded] = ((ldat[expanded] == "true" || ldat[expanded] === true) ? true : false) &&
    ldat[loaded];
```

to the following

```
ldat[expanded] = ((ldat[expanded] == "true" || ldat[expanded] === true) ? true : false) &&
    (ldat[loaded] || ldat[loaded] === undefined);
```

See [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTreeXml1__.htm) used the fixed code.

Comment: Thank you! I found this old bug with the load parameter but the creator said it's resolved.. some months ago. I didn't figure out how to apply the workaround in the new version just to try because source code has changed, but it actually works. Thanks!

Comment: @MihalisBagos: You are welcome! I will try to analyse the code of `setTreeNode` a little more and will post my suggestion how to fix the bug to trirand. If I'll do this I'll inform you about.

Comment: @MihalisBagos: I updated my answer with a suggestion for the bugfix.